# Typescript: How to transform function chain to Tagged Template literal?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, template-literals

Till now I have this (missing implementation is not important here):

```js
interface Context {
  User:     "OK"      | "KO"                    //  | "..."
  Password: "valid"   | "invalid"               //  | "..."
  Message:  "Welcome" | "Invalid credentials"   //  | "..."
  // ...
}

// I = Input, O = Output, H = Header
declare var I :Context , O :Context

interface Examples<H extends unknown[]> { // by @jcalz :)
  (...rows: H): Examples<H>
}


// this syntax is function chain with type safety and autocomplete
declare function Examples<H extends unknown[]>(...rows: H): Examples<H>

Examples
( I.User , I.Password , O.Message             )
( "OK"   , "valid"    , "Welcome"             )
( "KO"   , "invalid"  , "Invalid credentials" )
  
 
declare var ExamplesTTL_ideal: any 

// and this is ideal syntax sample with TTL - where first param is header and rest should be rows of type header

ExamplesTTL_ideal `
${[ I.User , I.Password , O.Message              ]}
${[ "OK"   , "valid"    , "Welcome"              ]}
${[ "KO"   , "invalid"  , "Invalid credentials"  ]}
`
```

Here it is all in [Typescript Playground](https://tsplay.dev/w6vpvw)

The question is - what should be declaration of ExampleTTL_ideal instead of :any ?

Regards.

Comment: I'm confused by the name `rows` in your `ExamplesTTL_close` function. The values that will go there are *column* values (`I.User`, `I.Password`, and `O.Message` in the first call to `ExamplesTTL_close`)...?

Comment: Uh, your types are *crashing* the type checker; I am seeing "Uncaught Error: too much recursion" in the console here.  Something about `declare function foo<T>(): typeof foo<T>` is *very very bad*.  Could you possibly refactor so as not to use that technique, such as [using an interface](https://tsplay.dev/N9nO1m)?  Otherwise I can't get much of anything good to happen at all here.  First thing I'm doing here is looking to see if this is reported as a TS github issue

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes may be also column from your point of view

Comment: I just opened [ms/TS#51202](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/51202) (although maybe this is a monaco editor issue and not a TS one).  Anyway, @qwertys, unless you're asking about this craziness, I strongly suggest you [edit] the question so as not to have it

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mMBz1W) meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?  (Please mention @jcalz in a reply so I am notified.)

Comment: @jcalz your approach meets my need - thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach here would look like this:

```
declare function ExamplesTTL<H extends string[]>(
  text: TemplateStringsArray, ...rows: [...H][]): ExamplesTTL<H>;

interface ExamplesTTL<H extends string[]> {
  (text: TemplateStringsArray, ...rows: [...H][]): ExamplesTTL<H>;
}
```

The function is [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in `H`, intended to be a [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) of string [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) (or [unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of string literals).  We want `rows` to be an array of such tuples.  If we're lucky, the compiler will use the first element in the `rows` array to infer `H`, and then *check* that subsequent elements in the array conform to it.

Note that in order to give the compiler a hint that `H` should be a tuple, we use [the variadic tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) `[...H]`.

Since you want the function to return a function of the same type except that `H` is no longer generic, I defined the `ExamplesTTL<H>` generic *type*.  Conceptually, the `ExamplesTTL<H>` type is equivalent to `typeof ExamplesTTL<H>` [instantiation expression](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-7.html#instantiation-expressions), but I've given it a new name so as to avoid a vicious circularity (see [ms/TS#51202](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/51202)).

---

Let's test it out:

```
const x = ExamplesTTL`
${[I.User, I.Password, O.Message]}
${["OK", "valid", "Welcome"]}
${["KO", "invalid", "Invalid credentials"]}
`;
// const x: ExamplesTTL<["OK" | "KO", "valid" | "invalid", 
//   "Welcome" | "Invalid credentials"]>

x`${["OK", "valid", "Welcome"]} ${["oops"]}`; // error!
// ------------------------------> ~~~~~~
//Type '"oops"' is not assignable to type '"OK" | "KO"'.(2322)

const y = ExamplesTTL`
${["a", "b", "c"]}${["a", "b", "d"]}`; // error!
// --------------------------> ~~~
// Type '"d"' is not assignable to type '"c"'.(2322)
```

Looks good.  The type of `x` is inferred as `ExamplesTTL<["OK" | "KO", "valid" | "invalid", "Welcome" | "Invalid credentials"]>` as desired, and thus subsequent calls to `x` constrain its input to that type (so `["oops"]` is bad).  And if you try to call `ExamplesTTL` with inconsistent tuple types, any inconsistency in the subsequent array entries are marked as an error.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIHtwQB5mQbwChlkBVAZ2gC5kAiAeQGlbkAfOx+lkn3vvgPQCS7WgDoJtYsgAKccuQDu6KABMatAG5wANsFUtRobXoP9zJISLoSxUkgFkICuAHMIGgOoQdCdAFsIQzoASRATfWQEKAhVCHBgXXJuZCs2G0lpK1tCAF9CQisQ5ABeZDCABwBXMAAaZHpShprquuQACSb2iDg4qEI4hB04GORtKHKaDCxcevopzEhcAsJQSFhEFABRbDh-Cp1nABUjgBkAHk6cSBBVcmRyMChQVwBtAF0APgJpAAolsA0I4QfbDSAAZSeL3IAEEoFA4ABPeq2KDoRTkGivWztd4fACUNB2ewOxzOl0+AG48gMIEMRigYFUQAgwMBMMhiaCyRcrrh4ncHlCQG8vr9pACgSCDnAIcLXLD4UiURI0RisTi8e9CZzdtzyCdeVSCn4QI9kNgmlzSQazgADQgAEnwrxCYgo0HqbrkCmUajmYicLnc73yzteDGY9S0un0tGj3l8ASCoadLtonHjdGMsYM0bCEVUURicQSSVoqbt1KspvN2CJepthvOEaYwQzXGjhfbOdMWdoib8gXbBdzxdi8TZ5a+BWwdvDkf73YTPiHKdyyAX6HQFWSoarqWE0DRUAAhIVhABaa83293+8P6-fAB+r7fF6OiIqKAA5LRt7utA-sgwD3CA6B4PI5DAK4IBwAARocyBgOgyFfr+i7pB2QFiL8ABMADMeF4fiJqYOaiJWo2hy2qcDoLnA-bwf2CAVrkDFMf2Bj7pSh7IMeKjnlYj4iSJL6vheyCft+yB-gYwGgcg4GQQoMFwYhKAoWhMl-qxP64YRxH4kAA)